# jQuery date validation working fine in Chrome but not working in IE

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a date validation in which if the user doesn't select any date, the default date "0001-01-01" will be displayed in the UI. this validation is working fine in Chrome but it's not working in Microsoft Edge. I have 2 such dates one is a start date and another is the end date. so the end date value is 9999-12-31 which is working fine. I can see the date in the UI for the end date. I just have the issues with the start date.

```
 if ($("#my-end-date").val() == null || $("#my-end-date").val() == "undefined" || $("#my-end-date").val() == "")
            {
                $("#my-end-date").val("9999-12-31");
                e.model.set("EndDate", "9999-12-31");
            }
  if ($("#my-start-date").val() == null || $("#my-start-date").val() == "undefined" || $("#my-start-date").val() == "")
            {
                $("#my-start-date").val("0001-01-01");
                e.model.set("StartDate", "0001-01-01");
            }
```

if I do like this

```
    if ($("#my-start-date").val() == null || $("#my-start-date").val() == "undefined" || $("#my-start-date").val() == "")
                        {
                            var mydate = new Date(0001,01,01);
                            $("#my-start-date").val(mydate );
                            e.model.set("StartDate", mydate );
                        }
```

the default dates that are displayed in the Ui is 02/01/1901. the date formate displayed in the UI are mm/dd/yyyy.

any help will be great. thank you.

Comment: generally the default date values should be valid values and not some hypothetical values. In your case min and max, dates seem to be hypothetical. Try changing the values and see if they work.

Comment: I know it's hypothetical but if I change the start date to 02/01/1901, it's working. but I have to set it to 0001/01/01.